# How to show AccessDenied errors on the active page with CanCan in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I am trying to find a way to display my flash errors on the active page without the `redirect_to` method.

By the way, the standard `flash[:alert] = exception.message` didn't show me any error messages, so I changed it to `flash[:error]`.

Thanks for any advice!

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|  
    flash[:error] = exception.message  
    redirect_to deadlines_path  
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash.now[:alert] = exception.message
  render 'something_else'
  return false
end
```

without a redirect.

Comment: thx for your response, but the flash.now[:alert] doesnt display anything :(

Comment: Are you displaying it in that new rendered file? With something like <p><%= flash[:alert] %></p>?

Comment: Yes I put flash:alert in the rendered file, but its not displaying the error. Only when I use flash:error