# if cancan access is denied it displays an error page or movie to another page, how to stay on same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have used cancan and i have used

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|  
  flash[:error] = "Access denied!"  
  redirect_to root_url  
end
```

in my application controller but i want to stay on the same page where i perform that action and if possible a pop up window  just showing

`you are not authorised to perform this action`

How to customize so as to stay in the same page wherever the unauthorized action is performed? please help me doing this.

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767460/how-to-show-accessdenied-errors-on-the-active-page-with-cancan-in-rails3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `redirect_to :back`:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|  
  flash[:error] = "Access denied!"  
  redirect_to :back  
end
```

Comment: This is what i was asking. Also can you tell me how to make an alert using popup showing you are not authorized and clicking on ok button has to put me in the same page.

Comment: you can show flash[:error] message on the same page or if you want alert popup, you can do it with javascript

Comment: ok. Thankyou so much. Also i have posted one more question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047877/reset-password-link-asks-user-to-sign-in pls help me.

Comment: In Rails 5, we will use [redirect_back](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back) like:

    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path